# AJAX success function not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I made ajax function for button that if i click it means 'like' and record to database
then the button is gonna change to 'dislike' and if click again it means delete record.

In the record part is working fine but i'm stuck on success function
this is my whole javascript..

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function addLikes(userFRIEND,action) {
  $('.demo-tutor #tutorial-'+userFRIEND+' li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('#tutorial-'+userFRIEND+' #rating').val((index+1));
    if(index == $('.demo-tutor #tutorial-'+userFRIEND+' li').index(obj)) {
      return false; 
    }
  });


  $.ajax({
  url: "add_follow.php",
  data:'userFRIEND='+userFRIEND+'&action='+action,
  type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function(){
    $('#tutorial-'+userFRIEND+' .btn-likes').html("<img src='http://www.seedsofpeace.org/gif/loading.gif' />");
  },
  success: function(data){
  var followings = parseInt($('#likes-'+userFRIEND).val());
  switch(action) {
    case "like":
    $('#tutorial-'+userFRIEND+' .btn-likes').html('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs unlike" onClick="addLikes('+userFRIEND+',\'unlike\')">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Unfollow&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>');
    followings = followings+1;
    break;
    case "unlike":
    $('#tutorial-'+userFRIEND+' .btn-likes').html('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs like" onClick="addLikes('+userFRIEND+',\'like\')">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Follow&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>')
    followings = followings-1;
    break;
  }
  $('#likes-'+userFRIEND).val(followings);
  if(followings>0) {
    $('#tutorial-'+userFRIEND+' .label-likes').html(followings);
  } else {
    $('#tutorial-'+userFRIEND+' .label-likes').html('0');
  }
  }
  });
}
    </script>
```

I try to put alert on success function and it's work.
so I think the errors must be on

```
$('#tutorial-'+userFRIEND+' .btn-likes').html("blabla");
```

> > ***#tutorial-'+userFRIEND+' .btn-likes***

but to be honestly i don't know how to fix it

and this is the html that relate with javascript 
(I'll show via picture for easy looking.)

[HTML fig.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHGqC.jpg)

thank you so much for every suggestion.

Comment: Try an alert or console.log of the variable 'action' right before the switch to make sure it hasn't fallen out of scope before the success function is called.

Comment: i tried an alert with action and it's work. btw beforeSend function isn't work also i guess there are somethings went wrong in div class and id path @Joe

Comment: This may all be a typo.  In the html image, your div has `id="tutorial-1;"`. I think if you remove the semicolon from the id attribute then the selector will match.

Comment: omg how dumb i am. it's working ! I put that semicolon in wrong place thanks Joe i owe you >_< @Joe

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Since this was a simple typing mistake, I'm going to recommend that this question be closed.

Comment: sure ;D  thank you again ,i'll concentrate with syntax more.

Answer (score 0):

seems you do wrong with the posted data, try do it in this format:

```
  url: "add_follow.php",
  data: {
    userFRIEND:userFRIEND, 
    action:action
  },
  type: "POST",
```

then try this selector:

```
 console.log(userFRIEND) // this really logs "1" ? 
 $('#tutorial-'+userFRIEND+').find('.btn-likes').html("blabla");
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but its still not work i'm not sure how to put   console.log(userFRIEND)

Comment: in your success function, if it logs `1` , `$('#tutorial-'+userFRIEND+').find('.btn-likes').html("blabla");` should work

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using jquery without

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code
});
```

Be sure to put you js code at the end of the page and, as mentioned before me, put and object in ajax data property

Comment: jQuery's ajax method also accepts a query string in the data property, so that shouldn't be causing any issues.  There is no reason to define the function inside of a document ready handler, it is not executed until it is called by a click handler anyway.